# Finding the spectrum of a Sturm-Liouville problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

I have the following [Sturm-Liouville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory) problem for $0 \le x\le \pi$

$$y'' + \lambda y=0, \qquad y(0) = 0, \qquad y(\pi)+y'(\pi) = 0 $$

How do I find the spectrum of the problem? And how will the spectrum change if instead of $0 \le x \le \pi$ and $y(0)=0$, we have $0<x<\pi$ and $y(0)-y'(0)=0$ instead?

edit: for the first problem i got that the spectrum is $\lambda>0$ since for $=0$ or $<0$ i  get the trivial solution (don't know if i'm correct though).
As for the second problem, i've got $\lambda=1,-1$ (and also the trivial solution). are there any issues with those solutions?

Comment: Do you know how to find the general solution for any $\lambda$?

Comment: i found the trivial solution for $\lambda =0$ but i'm getting lost at smaller or larger than 0

Comment: Hint: Assuming $\lambda > 0$, the general solution of your differential equation is $A\sin(x\sqrt{\lambda}) + B\cos(x\sqrt{\lambda})$, where $A$ and $B$ are unknown coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Solving for

$$
y'' + \lambda^2 y=0, \qquad y(0) = 0 
$$

we have

$$
y=c_2\sin(\lambda x)
$$

and then

$$
y(\pi)+y'(\pi)=0\Rightarrow c_2\left(\lambda\cos(\lambda\pi)+\sin(\lambda\pi)\right)=0
$$

this follows for all $\lambda_k$ such that $\lambda_k\cos(\lambda_k\pi)+\sin(\lambda_k\pi)=0$ as can be depicted in the following plot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Every solution of $-y''=\lambda y$, $y(0)=0$ can be normalized by adding a normalization condition such as $y'(0)=1$:
$$
        -y''=\lambda y,\;\; y(0)=0,\; y'(0)=1.
$$
Any solution of the above without the condition $y'(0)=1$ is a scalar multiple of the solution with $y'(0)=1$. The solution of this equation is unique, and is given by
$$
               y_{\lambda}(x)=\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)}{\sqrt{\lambda}},\;\; \lambda\ne 0.
$$
This also works in the limiting case as $\lambda\rightarrow 0$ to give $y_0$:
$$
            y_0(x)=x
$$
Every solution of $-y''=\lambda y, y(0)=0$, is a scalar mutliple of $y_{\lambda}$. The eigenvalues of your problem are the values of $\lambda$ for which
$$
                 y_{\lambda}(\pi)+y_{\lambda}'(\pi)=0 \\
             \frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}+\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)=0.
$$
A common way to write this eigenvalue equation is:
$$
            \tan(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)=-\sqrt{\lambda}.
$$
The eigenvalues of your problem are the solutions $\lambda$ of the eigenvalue equation. It is possible in such problems for there to be negative solutions $\lambda$.